# How to map query result to member class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A MemberA { get;set; }
}
```

How to properly make query to map the results to all members?

```
var query = "SELECT [Table1].[Id] as [Id], [Table2].[Name] as [Member_A].[Name] FROM [Table1]"; // this is more complex query, there are more tables, columns, joins
ObjectResult<B> result = _context.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<B>(query);
```

This doesn't work. `result.MemberA` is null. How to make it?

Comment: Show your OrderViewModel code.

Comment: Just changed `OrderViewModel` to `B`.